# Simple way to render inputted component inside generic component

Tags: angular

I have seen an approach to do this using `ng-content`, but i can't do it this time (Also, seems that this isn't the best approach for this kind of problem).

Basically, what i want is something similar to this:

```
@Input title: string;
@Input component: Component; <--- This
```

Or something as simple as this.
I just need to be able to render a component (For example, a ButtonComponent) inside this component, but i already used `ng-content` (I am making basically an expansible container, but it can receive any components to display on the right side).
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*ngComponentOutlet` directive.

For example:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
```

Of course with this directive, you have to add input component to entryComponents array too.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcccxd)

Comment: It is not a solution to his problem. And also lacks explanation.

Comment: It's the solution to his problem. This directive allows rendering the component. In this case, it's simple usage.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do such a thing is to use dynamically loaded components.

In your host component you should do the following:

add a `<ng-container #btnContainer>` where you want the button to be rendered in your template, and place a reference to it at the component class with `@ViewChild('btnContainer', {static: true}) btnContainer`.

Then receive ComponentFactoryResolver on the host component's constructor (it will be injected).

```
 constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
```

then somewhere else, you resolve the factory to that component, and insert it on the ng-container you added in the template.

```
insertButton() {
    const buttonFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ButtonComponent);
    //clear the container to be sure it is empty
    this.btnContainer.viewContainerRef.clear();
    const btnRef = this.btnContainer.viewContainerRef.createComponent(buttonFactory);

    //If you want to set some data to the ButtonComponent you do as following
    //Example: if the button has a @Input() text attribute.
    btnRef.instance.text = "I'm working"; 

}
```

Every dynamically loaded components should be added to the entryComponents array of the module it's part of. So add it as follow:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [ ... ],
  entryComponents: [ ButtonComponent ]  <----- here
})
```

The docs: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: You have the same result using `*ngComponentOutlet` directive and without unnecessary logic. Of course with this directive, you have to add `ButtonComponent` to `entryComponents` array too.

Comment: You can't just @Input component and then pass it to the ng-container. There's no point in binding a component via @input(). What he wants is a dynamically loaded loaded component, as described in the docs. I just brought the official solution here. There's no unnecessary logic, that's the right thing to do. Please, use StackBlitz or something as an example of your solution. Let me see it in action.

Comment: Now i got your point, it indeed is a possible solution. But even your answer lacking information for him, i'll remove the dislike. Post this stackBlitz link in your answer too, will help who reads it.